# Derivative of $F^TF$ with respect to $F$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I stacked with evaluating the derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial\left(F^TF\right)}{\partial F}~~ {\rm and}~~ \frac{\partial^2\left(F^TF\right)}{\partial F^2}
$$
in terms of $F\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$. Any hint or any idea would be acknowledged.

Comment: I think you need to define the meaning of the symbols $\frac{\partial g}{\partial F}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial F^2}$ for a function $g:\mathbb R^{3\times 3}\to\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ first.

Comment: @ Asatur Khurshudyan , you gave the green chevron to answer's greg. Then I suppose (I hope so) that you understood his post. Can you write the value of $\dfrac{\partial ^2 W}{\partial F_{i,j}\partial F_{k,l}}$ ? I am curious to see that.

Comment: @loupblanc Is this what they call an eloquent silence, from this OP, or what?

Comment: @ Did , I agree. Quite hilarious.

Comment: From his answer the linear elasticity energy functional can be reduced, that was the reason for acceptance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to approach this sort of problem is to use differentials rather than the chain rule.

This is because the chain rule requires intermediate quantities which are 3rd & 4th order tensors, which are difficult to work with, whereas differentials are ordinary vector and matrix quantities.

For convenience, let $$\eqalign{M=F^TF-I\cr\cr}$$
Use the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and this new variable to rewrite the function and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 W &= \frac{1}{2}\|M\|^2 \cr
   &= \frac{1}{2}M:M \cr\cr
dW &= M:dM \cr
   &= M:\big(\,dF^TF+F^TdF\,\big) \cr
   &= (FM^T+FM):dF \cr
   &= 2\,FM:dF\cr
   &= 2\,(FF^TF-F):dF \cr\cr
\frac{\partial W}{\partial F} &= 2\,(FF^TF-F) \cr\cr
}$$
Now let's proceed from the gradient to the the hessian (second derivative). Note that the gradient is a matrix, 
$$G=2\,(FF^TF-F)$$
so the hessian will be a 4th order tensor
$${\mathbb H} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial F}$$
Let's start with the differential of $G$
$$\eqalign{
dG &= 2\,(dF\,F^TF+F\,dF^TF+FF^TdF-dF) \cr\cr
}$$
To simplify further, we need 2 special (isotropic) tensors $({\mathbb E},{\mathbb B})$ with components
$$\eqalign{
{\mathbb E}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl}\cr
{\mathbb B}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{il}\,\delta_{jk}\cr
}$$
Then
$$\eqalign{
dG &= 2\,({\mathbb E}F^TF+F{\mathbb E}F^T:{\mathbb B}+FF^T{\mathbb E}-{\mathbb E}):dF \cr
{\mathbb H} &= 2\,({\mathbb E}F^TF+F{\mathbb E}F^T:{\mathbb B}+FF^T{\mathbb E}-{\mathbb E}) \cr\cr
}$$
Finally, you wished to evaluate the hessian at $F=I$, which simplifies things greatly
$$\eqalign{
{\mathbb H} &= 2\,({\mathbb E}+{\mathbb E}:{\mathbb B}+{\mathbb E}-{\mathbb E}) \cr
 &= 2\,({\mathbb E}+{\mathbb B}) \cr
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Merging of two answers:

First a remark about derivatives in the algebra $M_3$ of matrices of size $n\times n$.

You need to give a meaning to $\frac{\partial F}{\partial F}$. The upper $F$ is a function of the $n^2$ elements of $F$ and you are calculating a derivative w.r.t. all the $n^2$ elements of $F$. So a way to write is
$ \frac{\partial F_{ij}}{\partial F_{kl}}=\delta_{ij,kl}$  which has $n^2\times n^2$ components. Now the derivative  in the direction $H\in H$ is then $\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial F} H \right)_{ij} = \sum_{kl} \delta_{ij,kl}H_{kl} = H_{ij}$ an extremely cumbersome way of writing.
Should really be avoided if possible.

Setting $X=M_{3}({\Bbb C})$, $f:X \rightarrow X$,  $f(F)=F^T F$:
$$ f(F+H)= (F+H)^T (F+H) = F^T F + (F^T H + H^T F) + H^T H$$
which is identified with  $f(F) + f'(F).H + 1/2 f''(F).(H,H) + \ldots$
where $f'(F).H = F^T H + H^T F$ is the 1st derivative (acting upon $H$) and $f''(F).(H,K) = H^T K + K^T H$ is the second derivative (symmetric bilinear form).

Now  a shortcut (if you don't worry too much about rigour?) to get the derivative of a differentiable function $W$ at $F$ in a direction $H$ all you need to calculate: $\frac{\partial W(F)}{\partial F} (H)=\frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0} W(F+tH)$.  Here $t$ is a just a usual real variable.

Let us take (from the commentary rather than the question, which should perhaps be reformulated?) $W(F)=\frac{1}{4} |F^T F-I|^2=\frac{1}{4} {\rm tr} ((F^T F-I)(F^T F-I))$ with
 $F\in X=M_{3}({\Bbb C})$. Let us find the derivative in a direction $H$:
$$ \frac{\partial W(F)}{\partial F}(H)= \frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0} W(F+tH) = ... = \frac{1}{2} {\rm tr} ((H^T F + F^T H) (F^T F-I))$$

The second derivative of this expression in the direction $K$ is:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 W(F)}{\partial F^2}(H,K)= \frac{d}{dt}_{|t=0}\frac{\partial W(F+tK)}{\partial F}(H)  = ... = \frac{1}{2} {\rm tr} ((K^T H + H^T K) (F^T F-I))+
\frac{1}{2} {\rm tr}( (H^T F + F^T H)(K^T F + F^T K) )$$
Setting $F=I$ and $K=H$ the first term vanishes and the result is: 
$$ \frac{\partial^2 W(F)}{\partial F^2}(H,H)_{|F=I} =\frac{1}{2}  
{\rm tr}( (H^T + H)(H^T + H) ) = \frac{1}{2} |H^T+H|^2.$$
 Thus,
$$ \frac{\partial^2 W(F)}{\partial F^2}_{|F=I} (F,F) =  
\frac{1}{2} |F^T+F|^2$$

Comment: I am sorry, but I can`t get any of my derivatives from your answer.

Comment: So it depends a bit on in what way your derivative should be described? Perhaps you mean with indices like: $\partial (F^T F)_{ij}/F_{kl}$ ?

Comment: Ideally, it should be written in terms of $F$. Maybe ${\rm tr}~F$, $|F|$, etc.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Even $g(F)=\partial (F^2)/\partial F$ is not just $2F$ !  Have you seen any examples in a lecture course before  this exercise? You may also try to calculate  $\partial F / \partial F$ (it is not that simple either).

Comment: Actually, I want to calculate
$$
\frac{\partial^2W(F)}{\partial F^2}\bigg|_{F={\rm Id}}(F,F),
$$
with $W(F)=0.25|F^TF-{\rm Id}|^2$. See Eq.(6.2) of
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.10048/epdf

So, I thought,
$$
\frac{\partial W(F)}{\partial F }=0.5(F^TF-{\rm Id})\frac{\partial F^TF}{\partial F}.
$$
Am I wrong?

Comment: I can't get hold of the paper from the link (if not paying). But what is the meaning with the vertical bars? Some norm?  Your derivative can not be expressed as you write it. The previous form makes sense. It is a bilinear form in which you insert $F$ and $F$. It happens in this case to evaluate to zero when $F=Id$ but that's a rather particular case.

Comment: It means that the derivative must be evaluated at $F={\rm Id}$.

Comment: For that one I know, but how about $W(F)=0.25 |F^TF-Id|^2$ ? As we are looking at matrices it is not so obsvious what $| \cdot|$ means.

Comment: It means Frobenius norm: $|F|^2={\rm tr}F^TF$.

Comment: Yes, it`s quite possible. How did you get that?

Comment: For example, if it means: $|A|^2={\mbox tr } A^TA$ then I think the result after a fairly long calculation is: $|F^T+F|^2$. I'll try to write it down in an answer...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expand using the product rule. It should be obvious how to simplify one of the resulting terms, so the problem will then be reduced to computing ${\partial(F^T)\over\partial F}$. One you have that, computing the second derivative should be easy.

As another hint, consider the analogous problem in elementary calculus. what would you guess the second derivative of $F^TF$ ought to be?

Comment: The first hint is useful, however, how to compute $\frac{\partial F^T}{\partial F}$? That is the main problem.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan That’s really going to depend on what you mean by a derivative of a matrix by a matrix. I second greg’s suggestion to start with differentials. Every operator that simply rearranges components commutes with the differential, so $\mathrm d(F^T)=(\mathrm dF)^T$.